# Touch Events not working in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, touch

I am new in Action Script.

I am trying to get the touch events. I implemented this.

```
Multitouch.inputMode=MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, taphandler);

function taphandler(evt:TouchEvent): void { 
   trace("touch events");
}
```

while taping on the screen the method not triggered.
I am using CS5.5 and Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Your function naming not the same.

(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, **tap handler**);

function **taphandler**(evt:TouchEvent):

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you replace the TouchEvent with the more commonly used MouseEvent.

Even if you try this on your phone (with adobe air) this will work the same as a touch event and the user will not notice any difference.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(evt:MouseEvent): void { 
   trace("click event");
}
```

Comment: i am developing a desktop  Air application

Comment: And when you debug you do it on a device with touch screen? Try mouse event.  You won't be disappointed.